# Dynamic array of strings / dynamic dictionary

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dictionary

beginner here

This is absolutely infuriating me, how do I create an array that holds strings where the length / amount of strings are unknown? I essentially want to create a dictionary where

```
array[0] = "word"

array[1] = "word2"

array[2] = "word3"
```

and so on

I tried :

```
array** = malloc(INIT); where init was defined as 10

memset(array, '\0', 10)
```

then, under a loop

```
array[i] = malloc(INIT)

array[i] = string from another source ( array2[i] )  (array2 is a char*)
```

but that just gives errors / junk text and I have no clue how to assign strings to the array

I'm having a hard time understanding pointers / jargon in general, I've looked at all the similar questions and can't understand any of the answers.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the _real_ code, semicolons and all, and not some obscure placeholders like _blabla_.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this -

```
    int main(){
    int i;
    char *arr[10];
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        char str[1000];
        scanf("%s", str);
        arr[0] = (char*) malloc(strlen(str));
        strcpy(arr[0], str);    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create an array of pointers to strings and in that way keep it flexible:

```
char** array = malloc(sizeof(char*)*n); // allocates an array of char* pointers
```

if you later need to extend the array use realloc

```
char** newarray = realloc(array,sizeof(char*)*(n+1));
if (newarray != NULL)
{
  array = newarray;
  ...
}
```

You must also remember to allocate space for where the pointers point to for storing your strings

```
array[i] = strdup("blabla");
```

or

```
array[i] = malloc(strlen("blabla")+1);
strcpy(array[i], "blabla" );
```

Comment: Or rather use a pointer to an array of pointers: `char* (*array)[n] = malloc(sizeof(*array));`